# Verify typed text in input text - Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing

I have a simple method for sending keys to a textbox, but sometimes the end letters are missing, or the whole text, yet selenium returns 'Passed' for this test step. This happens only in a specific dialog window which has 4 elements: 
1. Select
2. Input text
3. Save button
4. Cancel button

The test case selects a value from the select list, then types the given string to the textbox and clicks save.

Can I somehow verify right after the text is typed that it equals to the expected text? I tried with textboxelement.getText() but it returned null, probably because the cursor was still in the textbox and the text was not sent. I'd like to solve it without pressing a key like ENTER because it might close this dialog window.

My send text method:

```
public final void sendText(final String value, final String id) {
    final By locator = By.id(textOrVariableValue(id));
        final WebElement element = getElementByLocator(locator, ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator), 10, true);
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(textOrVariableValue(value));
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any child element present for `text box` where you trying to add text?

Comment: it looks like this: 
<div class="col-sm-8">
            <input id="newelementkey" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="value: newElementKey, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="validationMessage: newElementKey" style="display: none;"></div>
          </div> 
The alert div is shown if the validation for the input fails.

Answer (score 2):

On *sending keys to a textbox* and trying to *verify* right after the text is typed if *it equals to the expected text* will always *return* **null** and that is the **Expected Behavior**.

### Reason

When you invoke **`sendKeys()`**, it simply pastes the **Character String** within the textbox. No other action is performed and nothing is returned. So no change in the **`HTML DOM`**.

So, when you try to do :

```
textboxelement.getText()
```

**null** is returned.

Incase when you click on **Save** button the **`onClick()`** event of `Save` button performs the intended functions (calls to **`JavaScript`** / **`AJAX Scripts`**) which inturn changes the **`HTML DOM`** and the text is gets accomodated with the **`DOM Tree`**. Now if you try to :

```
textboxelement.getAttribute("attribute_name");
```

You would be able to retrive the text.

Finally, as you mentioned `without pressing a key like ENTER because it might close this dialog window` that is how the text would be accomodated in the **`DOM Tree`** for **`Selenium`** and your **`Automation Script`** to find out through **findElement()** or **findElements()**