# Grab value of input field using selenium and check if it is correct then console log message

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey everyone I am working with Selenium Webdriver, more specifically Chrome Webdriver and writing my tests using Javascript. I am currently stumped on a part of the code that just doesn't seem to work. I am typing in a value within the input field using the send.Keys function which works fine but I can't seem to grab that value and check if it is the value that I want... then console.log whether the number is correct or not.

So let's say the send.Keys function types in 5 but the correct value should be 10. How would I write a test that grabs that value that was typed and compare it to the correct value then console.log a message which states if the value is correct or not... I have been stuck on this for a day and really need some help. I have found 0 documentation on this. I don't know if I need to use assertions of something else to get this to work, but everything I've tried has failed.

I am testing a few different numbers... the numbers have to be less than or equal to a 100 but greater than 0. Also the input must be numeric. I just have no clue how to go about writing this test out, so any help is appreciated... thanks!

Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89a84dbc15ba4088719400be1f359045

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify typed text in input text - Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018972/verify-typed-text-in-input-text-selenium)

Comment: I solved this thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test the input yourself.  Selenium has well built assertion check methods to make it a test.

Use,  assert.equal('tested string', textValue);
And sometime you might need to wait before you copy the text string after sending.

Comment: I figured it would be an assertion method, but is there anyway you can explain to me where I would place that assertion in my code. This is my first time using Selenium unfortunately...

Comment: After SendKey(), you can do `String value = elements.getById(#id).getAttribute("value");
        Assert.assertEquals("Some text", value);` you'll need to consult the actual javascript equivalent names/methods

Comment: Does this need to be in a function? Or would I have to use .then() ?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WenoV.png I get this error when doing that.

Comment: .then() will do.

Comment: [1] -> then you have an incorrect item selected. Recheck your css selection.